# entity framwork tostring()fails with error

Tags: vb.net

Im trying in Visual Basic to lean the Entity Framework for accessing an SQL database.  Im told its simpler but that's not my current experience.  i have a simple SQL DB with one table and only two fields.  I can setup the connection fine.  but i cant read data.  when i use this code and there are even several iterations commented out

testEntities:

```
Dim test = New testEntities
'Dim result = test.Database.SqlQuery < main > ("Select * from  main").ToArray()
'Dim result() = test.Database.SqlQuery < main > ("Select * from main").ToArray()
Dim results = test.Database.SqlQuery(Of Array)("select * from mymain").ToArray()
```

I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The result type 'System.Array' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor

Please help.

Comment: I was going to format your code for you but I don't know what should be there and what shouldn't.  Please post code properly.  Copy it from the IDE, paste it into your question, select it and click the code button (pair of braces) on the tool bar.  That adds four spaces before each line and the block will then be automatically formatted as code.

Comment: Please make the title of your question actually relevant to the question.  There's no `ToString` in your code anywhere and the issue is actually about using `Array` type as a generic type parameter.  You should almost never be using `Array` at all.  If you want an array then specify the type, e.g. `String()` is a `String` array and `Integer()` is an `Integer` array.  That said, I don't see why you'd be using arrays at all there.

Comment: That doesn't look like EF at all.  You're doing it wrong.  Generally speaking, you create an instance of your custom `DbContext` class and then use LINQ to query one of its `DbSet` properties.  E.g. to query the `Thing` table would be something like `Dim things = myContext.Things.ToList()`.  If you want to filter then use a `Where` call, e.g.  `Dim things = myContext.Things.Where(Function(t) t.Stuff IsNot Nothing).ToList()`